# Pass Component Name as Argument and then attach method (not working?)

Tags: javascript, variables, arguments

Maybe I'm not using the right terms/names for my searches but I have not been able to find anything on this topic. I would have thought this would be an easy thing to find. What I'm doing is passing a component name to a function and then trying to use the component's name by attaching a method to it. I have confirmed (via Dev Tools) that the name is correctly being passed but when I use the variable and attach the method the specific request does not work. If I 'hard-code' the exact component name to the method it works perfectly. This makes me think the (various) ways I've been trying to attach the method to the variable name is incorrect (see various attempts below). Can you offer some direction here? Thank you.

Passing to Function ...

```
const grid_name = "grid_GroupA";
console.log(grid_name); // Shows grid_GroupA
msg_max(newItem, grid_name);
```

Function (only listing relevant parts)

```
function msg_max(newItem, grid_target) {
    console.log(grid_target); // Shows grid_GroupA
//  grid_GroupA.data.add(newItem); // This works ...
//  grid_target.data.add(newItem); // This does not work
//  (grid_target).data.add(newItem); // This does not work
//  [grid_target].data.add(newItem); // This does not work
//  grid_target + '.data.add(newItem)'; // This does not work
```

Thank you ...

**Edit ...**
In my attempt to provide detail I hope I haven't confused the issue.

In essence, my question is if I can type this exact string

```
grid_GroupA.data.add(newItem);
```

and it works for my function, how can I place a variable with the exact string "grid_GroupA" in front of ".data.add(newItem);" and have it seen the same as the line of code that works? Maybe my lack of knowledge here is getting in the way but isn't the line of code that works just a string that is then used to 'find' the object? So, if that assumption is correct, how do I create that same string with the variable? If my assumption is wrong I am a willing learner so I will be all ears. Thank you.

Comment: Please show us where your component is defined. Btw it would be much easier if you could just pass the component instance itself instead of its name, is that not possible?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Can you look at the comment I just posted to @Temoncher to see if that offers any clarification?

Answer (score -1):

I do not see how `grid_target` is an object. You are passing `grid_name`(which is a string) to the function, so `grid_target` will have no `data` property, because string doesn't have such a member.

P.S. snake_case is bad option for JavaScript, consider using cameCase instead

Comment: I'm new at this but I don't think I was trying to pass the object. Only the name. My hope was to add the 'string' to the front of the method. As support for this approach, if I just type in the exact characters in front of the method it works fine. Am I wrong here? If I type in the exact same sequence of letters it works. I thought that the 'string' you are referring to should work as well?

Comment: @Bergi is right on this one, to debug your code we need to understand what is this `component` that you are talking about. What is `grid_GroupA` that you are reffering to in second block of code? (please use codesandbox.io next time to provide your solution, it will be much easier to help)

Comment: Yes, you are mistaken, JavaScript do not just 'finds objects by names'. To use some object you need to declare it as a variable or constant with `var`, `let` or `const`, and then it will be accessible. With `grid_target` JS thiks that you try to get `data` property from simple string, not from object. To solve this issue you can try to store your objects in an array and access them by index or `find` method.

Comment: Okay. Then I need to go back to the drawing board and not waste any more of your time. Thank you for the education and the direction. I was barking up the wrong tree (for several hours!). I appreciate the info. Thank you.